# How do I shut down a Buildbot master from the web UI?

Tags: buildbot

I have enabled `gracefulShutdown=True` per the [documentation](http://docs.buildbot.net/0.8.8/manual/cfg-statustargets.html#authorization). Where do I find the "shutdown" option in the web UI?

Comment: If you dont get an answer here, write to the [mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/buildbot-devel), there isn't much buildbot community in SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the "Graceful Shutdown" button at:

```
buildbot/buildslaves/<NAME>
```